# Recyclerview and Picasso - картинки отображаются только раз

Tags: android, recyclerview, picasso

Есть адаптер RecyclerView, который в себе хранит данные для отображения. Картинки загружаются первый раз нормально, а вот второй раз (когда пролистал, а потом вернулся к элементу) уже не отображаются. В чем может быть проблема?

```
public class ChatConversationRvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    protected MainActivity mainActivity;
    private ArrayList<MessageModel> messages;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_conversation_rv_item, parent, false);
        return new mLocViewHolder(v);}

    private static class mLocViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView userName;
        TextView message;
        ImageView imageView;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;

        private mLocViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_name_text_view);
            message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_message_text_view);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_image_image_view);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        mLocViewHolder mHolder = (mLocViewHolder) holder;
        final MessageModel model = messages.get(position);
        mHolder.userName.setText(model.getClientNickname());

        if (model.getMessageType().equals("text")) {
            mHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHolder.message.setText(model.getMsg());
        }

        if (model.getMessageType().equals("photo")) {
            mHolder.message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Picasso.with(context).load(model.getMsg()).into(mHolder.imageView);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }


    public void setActivity(MainActivity act) {
        this.mainActivity = act;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<MessageModel> incomingData) {
        messages = incomingData;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: в коде адаптера, который Вы загрузили, вроде проблем нет. Следует посмотреть в сторону подготовки данных т.е. на класс MessageModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте после получения типа события не только скрывать, но и показывать нужные вьюхи. Как-то так:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    mLocViewHolder mHolder = (mLocViewHolder) holder;
    final MessageModel model = messages.get(position);
    mHolder.userName.setText(model.getClientNickname());

    if (model.getMessageType().equals("text")) {
        mHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mHolder.message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mHolder.message.setText(model.getMsg());
    } else {
        mHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (model.getMessageType().equals("photo")) {
        mHolder.message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(context).load(model.getMsg()).into(mHolder.imageView);
    } else {
        mHolder.message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло. Из-за того, что вьюхи используются повторно, нужно каждый оаз отображать/скрывать нужные.