# Способен ли picasso правильно работать с recyclerview?

Tags: android, recyclerview, picasso

Здравствуйте!

Я намеревался использовать picasso в своём проекте в recyclerview, но выяснилось, что у него нет функций(во всяком случае при беглом ознакомлении не нашёл), которые бы позволили прерывать наложение изображения на imageview в случае необходимости.

Объясню зачем мне это и чего я опасаюсь.

Предположим, что у вас медленный интернет и загрузка изображения занимает 15 секунд и у нас большой список изображений, скажем их сотня. Если выполнить стандартный код recyclerview с использование picasso, то он будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
     Picasso.with(context).load("url").into(viewHolder.postImage);
}
```

Результатом работы такого кода, вполне ожидаемо, будет появление изображения в нужном месте. Но! Если пользователь сдвинет список, до полной загрузки изображения, то recyclerview может попытаться использовать тот viewHolder.postImage, который мы передали picasso в прошлый раз. В результате такого действия, картинка появится не там, где мы это ожидаем. Грубо говоря, вместо первой позиции, появится на 10.

Однако немного погуглив, я обнаружил, что другие используют эту связку, например:

[Recyclerview and Picasso - картинки отображаются только раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583414/recyclerview-and-picasso-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364837/picasso-does-not-work-with-recycler-view-in-android

Подскажите пожалуйста, я прав в своих опасениях и picasso не получится нормально использовать с recyclerview или есть какая-то особенность, благодаря которой это всё таки возможно?

Comment: плейсхолдер можно установить (пикасо позволяет указать картинку-заглушку, которая будет появляться, пока основное изображение не получено). Это нейтральное маленькое локальное изображение, одинаковое для всех айтемов

Comment: А разница?
Первое изображение появится не на своём месте! Это главная проблема.

Comment: Более того, если второе изображение есть в кэше, то оно появится мгновенно, но первое заменит его, как только загрузится.

Comment: Самое простое, что можно сделать - отменить запросы для этого вью перед вызовом load: `Picasso.with(context).cancelRequest(viewHolder.postImage);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понимая что `ImageView` в позициях 1 и 10 используется один (используется паттерн `ViewHolder`), после пролистывания `ImageView` в позицию 10 можно сразу установить новый `url` адрес, например:

```
Picasso.with(context)
   .load("url_10")
   .into(viewHolder.postImage);
```

И если картинка из предыдущего `url` не была загружена, то она не будет применена. А если загрузилась, то она будет отображаться по умолчанию, а после загрузится картинка по `url_10`

Comment: Прошу! Забудьте о дефолтных картинках, я знаю о этой возможности и речь сейчас не о ней.

Comment: Такой вопрос, вот вы написали "установить новый url", вы имели ввиду, что picasso может распознавать какой url, к какому imageView применять?

Comment: @kvazik обновил ответ. По поводу вопроса: ответ да.